# DynamoDB vs S3 when using images

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

When it comes to images, everyone says use S3. I understand different tools are built for different purposes it's understandable S3 is the default go to. But for educational purposes, I'm curious when it would be a better idea to use DDB over S3.

Let's say for an app like tinder, can't you store the main profile image (let's say image1) in the ImageTable1 with highest read write capacity and the rest of 5 or so images in the respective tables with low read write capacity settings. Each of these tables would only require a Hash Key and not a sort key.

Or is this design still a bad idea? Wouldn't this design cost less than using S3 since S3 pricing is proportional to number of get put requests while DynamoDB pricing is based on preset read write capacity?

And yes, I'm very aware that DDB has a single item size limit of 400kb. So for this argument, let's assume each image is <400 KB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DynamoDB is a cheap database, yet pricier than you think.

We need to clarify what DynamoDB's capacity units really represent. Data is read in chunks of 4KB and written in chunks of 1KB as of May/2016. It means that a single (big) object may consume more than one capacity unit, and multiple (tiny) objects may consume a single capacity unit when queried together.

So, a 100KB image require 25 RCU's. To sustain 50k image requests/hour, or ~14 requests/second = 14 * 25 = 350 RCU's which costs US$386.59/month in US-East, way more than S3 US$14.55/month.

Reference:

- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithTables.html#ItemSizeCalculations
- http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html#r=IAD&key=calc-9D2CA400-707F-4CEB-8153-4CF1CDBD9C57

Other advantages:

- Browser can fetch S3 object directly with pre-signed URLs (it is possible with DynamoDB but usually server processing is required);
- Objects are cached more easily;
- S3 costs what you consumed, instead of provisioned capacity

Comment: Thank you. I get it now!

Comment: I don't believe your "multiple (tiny) objects may consume a single capacity unit when queried together" is correct. When reading your answer it sounds like you are referring to multiple DynamoDB items. If I query for 80 items of 1 KB size, I consume 80 RCUs, not 20 (80 items * 1 KB).

Comment: @mkobit if you're talking about 80 separate queries, you're correct. please refer to the reference link I provided above.

Comment: Ahh, I think I misread your usage of "query" and equated it to the `BatchGetItem` type operation. With the case I described using `BatchGetItem` API, you would use 80 RCUs. With the case I described using `Query` API, you would get the 20 RCUs.

Answer (score 3):

Anything can be made to work, but S3 is definitely going to be the prefered method of storing images. IMO using DDB for this purpose would be silly - even if it works.

S3 is dirt cheap, redundant, and has 11 9's of reliability - not to mention you can pair it with cloudfront CDN and globally distribute your images/content closer to your clients world-wide to reduce latency - all with a few mouse clicks.

Comment: 11 9's reliability also applies for DDB as well. The cost of S3 for 10000 GET req is $0.0004 which for me sort of implies that it wants you to use this with a small number of large sized items, not <400 KB images used for a app like Tinder. What if I need to handle images that are <100KB and number of GET req is 50K/hr? It just seems like a wasteful solution when the items are not big enough. No?

Answer (score 1):

**DDB** doesn't allow individual records of size >400kb. If you prefer to store high resolution images. It might not be the best scenario to use DDB

> The maximum item size in DynamoDB is 400 KB, which includes both
>   attribute name binary length (UTF-8 length) and attribute value
>   lengths (again binary length). The attribute name counts towards the
>   size limit.

EDITED - Considering each image is <400KB

DynamoDB can fetch max of 100 records at one time which can be a problem for heavily popular apps like tinder considering the number of user. So this means you have to make thousands of requests to fetch images/data for your >1M users, which puts unnecessary load request on memory resources

> A single **BatchGetItem** operation can retrieve a maximum of 100 items.
>   The total size of all the items retrieved cannot exceed 16 MB.

[See the Limitations Documentation here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html)

Comment: You realize you can't run batch get request on S3 right? You can only download one object w/ a single get req.

Comment: S3 supports concurrency. Hence you can work in parallel. Thereby one request would suffice the entire need.

Comment: For the sake of argument, there is a limit of 10k of free get req a month. So are you saying, due to enabling concurrency, one can download more than 10k image objects freely a month? I doubt thats the case.